# How do I change audio source after changing slides?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, slider, html5-audio

So I've just started using the Slick Slider. It works pretty well but I'm having trouble changing the `src` in the html5 audioplayer after I switch slides. I have no clue how to go about this function. There are two carousels that are in sync with one another.

```
<div>
    <audio controls class="musicplayer" id="oned">
        <source id="song1" src="#" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
        <source id="song2" src="#" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
    </audio>
</div>

<div class="soapboxes" id="wrapper">
    <div><img src="images/pink and yellow trend@0.75x.png" class="pinkandyellow" alt="slider image" align="center"  ></div>
    <div><img src="images/green trend@0.75x.png" alt="slider image" align="center" ></div>
    <div><img src="images/red trend@0.75x.png" alt="slider image" align="center" ></div>
    <div><img src="images/pink trend@0.75x.png" alt="slider image" align="center" ></div>
</div>

<div class="music" id="wrapper">
    <div><p>Blah</p></div>
    <div><p>Blah1</p></div>
    <div><p>Blah2</p></div>
    <div><p>Blah3</p></div>
</div>

<script type= "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.soapboxes').slick({
            dots: true,
            arrows: true,
            autoplay: false,
            centerMode: true,
            mobileFirst: true,
            initialSlide: 1,
            slidesToScroll:1,
            asNavFor: '.music',
            slidesToShow: 3,
        });
    });
</script>

<script type= "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.music').slick({
            dots: false,
            arrows: true,
            autoplay: false,
            centerMode: true,
            accessibility: true,
            mobileFirst: true,
            initialSlide: 1,
            asNavFor:'.soapboxes'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I expect the `src` for the audio player to change in the event of the carousel slides containing images sliding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any jQuery plugin worth their salt has [documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for options and methods. In general, we would first see if there's an option that facilitates the use of audio files ... nope, so then look for methods that bind to events (commonly referred to as *"events"* or *"callbacks"*. In the [Settings section](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#settings) under *"Events"* there are several custom events. When hooking into a custom event of a slider type plugin it's best to find an event associated with going to and from a slide --

- we will use the ***beforeChange*** event which fires before slide change.
- we have to write our own callback function to actually change an `<audio>` tag's ***src*** value when the user goes to the next slide (that's when the **beforeChange** event occurs).
  **Signature**:

  ```
  $(SELECTOR).on('beforeChange', CALLBACK);
  ```

  **Demo:**

  ```
  $(".music").on("beforeChange", playlist);
  ```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    main {
      width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .slider,
    img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .player {
      width: 320px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="main slider">
      <div><img src="http://placeimg.com/320/180/people" alt="slider image"></div>
      <div><img src="http://placeimg.com/320/180/nature" alt="slider image"></div>
      <div><img src="http://placeimg.com/320/180/animals" alt="slider image"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="music slider">
      <div>Dog Days</div>
      <div>Jerky</div>
      <div>Righteous</div>
    </div>

    <audio class='player slider' src='http://soundbible.com/mp3/chinese-gong-daniel_simon.mp3' controls></audio>
  </main>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.main').slick({
      arrows: false,
      mobileFirst: true,
      asNavFor: '.music'
    });

    $('.music').slick({
      mobileFirst: true,
      asNavFor: '.main'
    });

    $('.music').on('beforeChange', playlist);

    function playlist(e, s, current, next) {

      var list = [
        'https://glsbx.s3.amazonaws.com/-/dd.mp3',
        'https://od.lk/s/NzlfOTEyMzgyNF8/jerky.mp3',
        'https://od.lk/s/NzlfOTEwMzM5OV8/righteous.mp3'
      ];

      $('.player')[0].src = list[next];
      $('.player')[0].load();
      $('.player')[0].play();

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much. For anybody else who comes across this, moving the <audio control> tag outside of the </main> tag could help if you get stuck